# create RealmRecyclerView for Realm Relational Object

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, realm

i have 2 object, and the have relation like this :

```
public class Acitivities extends RealmObject{
  @PrimaryKey 
  int id;
  String nameActivity;
  RealmList<Task> Task;
}

public class Task extends RealmObject{
  @PrimaryKey
  int id;
  String nameTask;
  String Description;
}
```

And this is my RecyclerView Adapter :

```
public class CustomRealmAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<Task, 
  CustomRealmAdapter.MyViewHolder>{
  OrderedRealmCollection<Task> data;
  RealmResult<Task> task;
  RealmResult<Activities> activities;

public CustomRealmAdapter(OrderedRealmCollection<Task> data, 
    RealmResult<Task> task){
    super(data,true);
    this.data = data;
    this.task = task;
}

}
```

at OnBindViewHolder i want to get Task, with the name of Activities, which is in holder i have 3 textview.

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Task tsk = task.ge(position);
    holder.nameActivity.setText(activities.getNameActivity);
    holder.nameTask.setText(tsk.getNameTask);
    holder.Description.setText(tsk.getDescription);
}
```

but i always get error, am i wrong? create RecyclerView for Task, because the RealmList is in Activities?
i want to show this RecyclerView in my Task Activity, not in Activities Activity.
Help me :(

Comment: `i always get error, am i wrong?` define "error"

Comment: btw I don't understand what exactly you want to display.

Comment: i have a Task Activity, which is i save in Task Object, and task object have relation with Activities, i want to make a recycler view for task, and also can view the name of activity which have relation with that task.

Comment: the error is name of activities is not show.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce how is it?

Answer (score 0):

To display the `Activity` that is linked to a given `Task`, you either need a bidirectional link (so Link would have `Activity activity;` as well), or you can define **the linking objects to `Task`** as a field of `Task` (Realm 3.1+).

```
public class Acitivities extends RealmObject{
  @PrimaryKey 
  int id;
  String nameActivity;
  RealmList<Task> Task;
}

public class Task extends RealmObject{
  @PrimaryKey
  int id;
  String nameTask;
  String Description;
  @LinkingObjects("Task")
  final RealmResults<Acitivities> activity = null;
}
```

Then

```
public class CustomRealmAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<Task, 
      CustomRealmAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

    public CustomRealmAdapter(OrderedRealmCollection<Task> data){
        super(data,true);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Task tsk = getData().get(position);
        holder.nameActivity.setText(tsk.activity.get(0).getNameActivity());
        holder.nameTask.setText(tsk.getNameTask());
        holder.Description.setText(tsk.getDescription());
    }
}
```